# run Java commands through a Shell script

Tags: java, bash, shell, bittorrent, vuze

I'm trying to code a shell script to start/stop torrents using vuze's console UI through SSH: 
https://wiki.vuze.com/w/Console_UI

I've downloaded vuze and everything works fine until I type this command:

**java -jar Azureus2.jar --ui=console**

After that, no command in my script works unless I quit that console.

Any solutions please? And if it's not feasible using shell scripts, any suggestions please?

Thanks.

Comment: try `java -jar Azureus2.jar --ui=console &`. Pay attention to **<space>&** at the end of the line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is, the commands I'm executing after that are no Shell commands but commands related to vuze like create or show torrents. Therefore I got an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the moment you run that command, your java program runs 'in the foreground', which means the rest of your script stops executing until your program exits.

If you want to keep on running the rest of your script *while your java program executes* you have to run your program in the background. One way to do that is as @Alp suggests:

`java -jar Azureus2.jar --ui=console &`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is, the commands I'm executing after that are no Shell commands but commands related to vuze like create or show torrents. Therefore I got an error message.